# Trigger to automatically add a record to another table

Tags: ios, sqlite

I've got a table:

**Items**

```
itemID int autoincrement
itemName text
```

**itemAvailability**

```
itemID       integer REFERENCES Items (itemID)
availability integer DEFAULT 0
```

I need a trigger to do:

When the user will add a record into Items table, the trigger must to automatically add a record into itemAvailability table.

itemAvailability.itemID=Items.itemID

At moment I came to this point and stuck:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateItemsAvailabilityTbl AFTER INSERT ON items
BEGIN
INSERT INTO itemAvailability (itemID)
VALUES (items.itemID)
END
```

well, it doesn't work for me. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two errors in your CREATE TRIGGER statement. 1. As it is written in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

> trigger actions may access elements of the row being inserted, deleted
>   or updated using references of the form "NEW.column-name" and
>   "OLD.column-name", where column-name is the name of a column from the
>   table that the trigger is associated with.
>   OLD and NEW references may only be used in triggers on events for
>   which they are relevant, as follows:
>
> INSERT NEW references are valid
>
> UPDATE NEW and OLD references are valid
>
> DELETE OLD references are valid

So you should write `new.itemID` instead of `items.itemID`. 2. The INSERT INTO statement should be terminated with a semicolon. Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateItemsAvailabilityTbl AFTER INSERT ON items
BEGIN
INSERT INTO itemAvailability (itemID)
VALUES (new.itemID);
END
```